# TypeError for Argument 2 in Solarium Client

Tags: symfony, drupal, drupal-8, solarium

I'm trying to start a client using Search_api_solr v4.1, Solarium v6.0 and symfony/event-dispatcher v3.4.47 but I keep getting a TypeError.

```
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Solarium\Core\Client\Client::__construct() 
must be an instance of Psr\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface, 
instance of Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher given
```

I'm not quite sure why it's expecting an instance of Psr\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface when all the documentation on solarium says to use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher.

My adapter and event Dispatcher is as below

```
use Solarium\Client;
use Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher; 

function get_search_query() {
$adapter = new Curl();
$eventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();

$config = ['endpoint' => ['localhost' => [
                'host' => $id,
                'port' => $port,
                'path' => '/',
                'collection' => '$core',],],];

$search = new Client($adapter, $eventDispatcher, $config);
$query = $search->createSelect();
}
```

Has anyone else ran into this issue or knows a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating the solarium client at `new Client()` the second parameter expects you to give a class implementing `Psr\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface`. However, in your use statement the EventDispatcher you are creating is `Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher`.

Change the use statement to the PSR event dispatcher and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you dig into the Symfony source you can view this :

```
if (interface_exists(PsrEventDispatcherInterface::class)) {
    /**
     * Allows providing hooks on domain-specific lifecycles by dispatching events.
     */
    interface EventDispatcherInterface extends PsrEventDispatcherInterface
    {
        /**
         * Dispatches an event to all registered listeners.
         *
         * For BC with Symfony 4, the $eventName argument is not declared explicitly on the
         * signature of the method. Implementations that are not bound by this BC constraint
         * MUST declare it explicitly, as allowed by PHP.
         *
         * @param object      $event     The event to pass to the event handlers/listeners
         * @param string|null $eventName The name of the event to dispatch. If not supplied,
         *                               the class of $event should be used instead.
         *
         * @return object The passed $event MUST be returned
         */
        public function dispatch($event/*, string $eventName = null*/);
    }
} else {
    /**
     * Allows providing hooks on domain-specific lifecycles by dispatching events.
     */
    interface EventDispatcherInterface
    {
        /**
         * Dispatches an event to all registered listeners.
         *
         * For BC with Symfony 4, the $eventName argument is not declared explicitly on the
         * signature of the method. Implementations that are not bound by this BC constraint
         * MUST declare it explicitly, as allowed by PHP.
         *
         * @param object      $event     The event to pass to the event handlers/listeners
         * @param string|null $eventName The name of the event to dispatch. If not supplied,
         *                               the class of $event should be used instead.
         *
         * @return object The passed $event MUST be returned
         */
        public function dispatch($event/*, string $eventName = null*/);
    }
}
```

So your issue is that `interface_exists(PsrEventDispatcherInterface::class)` returns false. THis interface comes from this package https://packagist.org/packages/psr/event-dispatcher so I would try a `composer require psr/event-dispatcher` to fix it.

EDIT : Your version of symfony's event dispatcher is outdated. Update to 5.3 to fix the issue.

Comment: I thought that as well and already `composer require psr/event-dispatcher` but it doesn't change the issue at all

Comment: Which version is installed ?

Comment: Version 1.0 is installed for psr/event-dispatcher